# find and remove words matching a substring in a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Is it possible to use regex to find all words within a sentence that contains a substring?

Example:

```
var sentence = "hello my number is 344undefined848 undefinedundefined undefinedcalling whistleundefined";
```

I need to find all words in this sentence which contains 'undefined' and remove those words.

```
Output should be "hello my number is ";
```

FYI - currently I tokenize (javascript) and iterate through all the tokens to find and remove, then merge the final string. I need to use regex. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have such string? Where do those `undefined` values come from?

Comment: the string comes from an external source (from a client) which I have no control of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It certainly is possible.

Something like start of word, zero or more letters, "undefined", zero or more letters, end of word should do it.

A word boundary is `\b` outside a character class, so:

```
\b\w*?undefined\w*?\b
```

using non-greedy repetition to avoid the letter matching tryig to match "undefined" and leading to lots of backtracking.

***Edit*** switch `[a-zA-Z]` to `\w` because the example includes numbers in the "words".

Comment: I ran a quick performance test and this regex is the fastest. http://jsperf.com/subdjauuasdj

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
str = str.replace(/ *\b\S*?undefined\S*\b/g, '');
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xI9qU5/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
\S*undefined\S*
```

Try this simple regex.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/5

Answer (score 1):

you can use str.replace function like this

```
str = str.replace(/undefined/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there are enough solutions with regular expressions, here is another one - using arrays and simple function that finds occurrence of a string in a string :)

Even though the code looks more "dirty", it actually works faster than regular expression, so it might make sense to consider it when dealing with **LARGE** strings

```
    var sentence = "hello my number is 344undefined848 undefinedundefined undefinedcalling whistleundefined";
    var array = sentence.split(' ');
    var sanitizedArray = [];

    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        if (undefined !== array[i] && array[i].indexOf('undefined') == -1) {
            sanitizedArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }

    var sanitizedSentence = sanitizedArray.join(' ');

    alert(sanitizedSentence);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/448bbumh/